# JPA Criteria API and making query with WHERE predicate containing .in()

Tags: jpa, criteria-api, where-in

I would like to make some query where my predicate is like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ProviderService> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ProviderService.class);
    // FROM
    Root<ProviderService> providerService = criteriaQuery.from(ProviderService.class);
    // SELECT
    criteriaQuery.select(providerService);

// WHERE'S PREDICATE
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if(providers != null && providers.size() > 0) {

        predicates.add(providerService.get(ProviderService_.provider).in(providers));
    } 
criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] { }));

    TypedQuery<ProviderService> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    return query.getResultList();
```

I check search for provider offers (ProviderService) that are supplied by any provider form collection (List) of providers.

I have received exception something like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unaware how to convert value [pl.salonea.entities.Provider@85eab3b6 : pl.salonea.entities.Provider] to requested type [java.lang.Long]
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.ValueHandlerFactory.unknownConversion(ValueHandlerFactory.java:258)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.ValueHandlerFactory.access$000(ValueHandlerFactory.java:34)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.ValueHandlerFactory$LongValueHandler.convert(ValueHandlerFactory.java:152)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.ValueHandlerFactory$LongValueHandler.convert(ValueHandlerFactory.java:139)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.InPredicate.<init>(InPredicate.java:130)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.InPredicate.<init>(InPredicate.java:108)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.in(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:529)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.expression.ExpressionImpl.in(ExpressionImpl.java:79)
```

EDITED:

I think it could have something to do with ProviderService composite Id that consists of (Provider, Service) and is defined as follows:

```
@Id
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "provider_id", referencedColumnName = "provider_id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
public Provider getProvider() {
    return provider;
}

public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}

@Id
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName = "service_id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT UNSIGNED")
public Service getService() {
    return service;
}

public void setService(Service service) {
    this.service = service;
}
```

And have proper IdClass as below:

```
public class ProviderServiceId implements Serializable {

private Long provider;
private Integer service;

/* constructors */

public ProviderServiceId() { }

public ProviderServiceId(Long providerId, Integer serviceId) {
    this.provider = providerId;
    this.service = serviceId;
}
// etc.
```

OR maybe there isn't such possibilities to compare entity attribute against list of possible values of that attribute (list of entities)

Comment: The message is clear: it expects a collection of Longs, and you're passing a collection of Providers. Since you didn't post code, we can't explain why, nor provide advice.

Comment: It's not so clear as this is Criteria API and it is predicate using in operator that should compare ProviderService._provider (type Provider) against list of providers List<Provider>

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You didn't post the code, so we can't comment.

Comment: It seems that this is comparing not Provider entity but its Provider ID against list of Provider entities... but queries like this: query = "SELECT ps FROM ProviderService ps WHERE ps.provider = :provider" works fine and i'm passing Provider entity as :provider param

Comment: This indeed looks like a bug. Not sure if it's caused by the composite ID,, but anyway, I'd avoid them like the plague. A probable workaround would be to use a join with provider, and add a predicate to check that the provider ID is in a Set of IDs (i.e. Long instances).

Comment: ok I have used:
// inner joining
  if(provider == null) provider = providerService.join(ProviderService_.provider);
  predicates.add(provider.in(providers));
and it seems to work now correctly... this is rather bug in Hibernate, cause analogue searching by provider works very well without joining when using NamedQueries

Answer (score 0):

Suggested joining seems to work correctly:

```
 // inner joining
 if(provider == null) provider = providerService.join(ProviderService_.provider);
 predicates.add(provider.in(providers));
```

I think that searching by passing list of Provider IDs rather than Provider entities will also work but haven't checked it.